# Проведение документа при помощи REST

Tags: 1с

Имеется конфигурация 1С 8.3 "Управление торговлей", в которой в рамках внутреннего товародвижения реализовано проведение документа "Перемещение товара с одного склада на другой".

Необходимо организовать обмен данными со сторонним приложением, чтобы при выполнении перемещения товаров в сторонней программе документ автоматически проводился в 1С (с регистрацией во всех журналах, фиксацией в регистрах, в общем, с автоматическим выполнением всех тех действий, которые выполняет кнопка «Провести и закрыть» - насколько я понимаю, при нажатии этой кнопки вызывается функция «Обработка проведения» документа «Перемещение товаров».

Вопрос: реализуема ли данная возможность с помощью интерфейса REST? Непонятность в том, что вот здесь http://v8.1c.ru/o7/201312rest/ указано, что "Недоступными на данный момент являются отчеты и обработки, команды..." - получается, мы не сможем с помощью REST запустить обработку (скажем, проведение документа) со стороны нашего приложения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Со стороны вашего приложения запустить сможете. Из этого же текста:

> В REST интерфейсе доступны реквизиты объектов конфигурации, доступны
>   операции создания, чтения, модификации и удаления данных, а также
>   некоторые методы встроенного языка. Например:
>
> Для документа - Post() и Unpost();
>
> **Методы объектов** встроенного языка выполняются POST-запросами.
>   Например, проведение документа:
>
> POST
>   /OData_Tests_Infobase/odata/standard.odata/Document_Invoice(guid'17ed2041-0345-11e3-b914-5404a6a68c42')/Post().

Вам не нужно запускать **обработку** (т.е. как объект метаданных конфигурации), вам нужно запустить **проведение самого документа**, и эта операция доступна. Другое дело, что действия, которые выполняет процедура ОбработкаПроведения() в модуле документа, строго говоря, не являются теми же самыми действиями, которые выполняет кнопка «Провести и закрыть», т.к. эта кнопка располагается в форме документа и в этой форме могут быть определены какие-то события и другие процедуры, модифицирующие реквизиты документа или выполняющие ещё какие-то действия. Так что перед вызовом процедуры ОбработкаПроведения() *(Post())* вам нужно позаботиться о том, чтобы документ был полностью заполнен, как надо.

Я так понимаю, вас ввело в заблуждение название процедуры «ОбработкаПроведения()». Но к тексту "Недоступными на данный момент являются отчеты и обработки, команды..." она не имеет никакого отношения; так называется **метод объекта**.